# Pandas: how to find and concatenate values

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I'm trying to replace and add some values in pandas dataframe object. I have to following code

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_items([('A', ["va-lue", "value-%", "value"]), ('B', [4, 5, 6])])
print df

df['A'] = df['A'].str.replace('%', '_0')
print df
df['A'] = df['A'].str.replace('-', '')
print df

#allmost there?
df.A[df['A'].str.contains('-')] + "_0"
```

How can I find the cell values in column A which contains '-' sign, replace this value with '' and add for these values a trailing '_0'? The resulting data set should look like this

```
          A  B
0   value_0  4
1   value_0  5
2     value  6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first keep track of the rows whose `A` needs to be appended with the trailing string, and perform these operations in two steps:

```
mask = df['A'].str.contains('-')
df['A'] = df['A'].str.replace('-|%', '')
df.ix[mask, 'A'] += '_0'
print df
```

Output:

```
         A  B
0  value_0  4
1  value_0  5
2    value  6
```